# Calculate the mean of a column by all combinations of the 2 other columns in R

Tags: r

I want to calculate the mean for every possible combination of 1st and 2nd column. So for the rows 1-2, 3, 4-6, and so on. How can I do that?

And 2nd question: How do I get the number of observations for every combination of L and M? 2 obs for A and A, 1 for A and B, 3 for A and I,...

```
        L      M    W
1       A      A 61.5
2       A      A 68.2
3       A      B 64.0
4       A      I 65.0
5       A      I 59.7
6       A      I 55.0
7       B      A 42.0
8       B      A 60.2
9       B      B 52.5
10      B      I 61.8
11      B      I 49.5
12      B      I 52.7
```

Comment: This is the same as asking to *calculate mean for every group*

Answer (score 3):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R` with a formula method and specify the `.` to select all other columns as grouping except the one of the `lhs` i.e. "W"

```
aggregate(W ~., df1, mean)
```

---

or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(across(where(is.character))) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(W), Count = n())
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   L [2]
  L     M      Mean Count
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 A     A      64.8     2
2 A     B      64       1
3 A     I      59.9     3
4 B     A      51.1     2
5 B     B      52.5     1
6 B     I      54.7     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(L = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B"), M = c("A", "A", "B", "I", "I", "I", "A", 
"A", "B", "I", "I", "I"), W = c(61.5, 68.2, 64, 65, 59.7, 55, 
42, 60.2, 52.5, 61.8, 49.5, 52.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Comment: It says there is no package named dplyr `> library(dplyr)
Fehler in library(dplyr) : es gibt kein Paket namens ‘dplyr’`

Comment: @CiroMertens I am guessing that `aggregate` should be available as it is `base R`.

Comment: When I try the other command it says "couldn't find object df1". What do I need to do to get the deployer package?

Comment: @CiroMertens It should be because your object name is different.  Can you show the object name

Comment: @CiroMertens The `dplyr` package can be installed with `install.packages("dplyr")`

Comment: I installed the package now and after I changed df1 for the name of the data set, I got what I wanted from the console. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(L, M) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(W),
            count=n())
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   L [2]
  L     M      mean count
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 A     A      64.8     2
2 A     B      64       1
3 A     I      59.9     3
4 B     A      51.1     2
5 B     B      52.5     1
6 B     I      54.7     3
```

Comment: It says `couldn't find function "%>%"`

Comment: You have to use `library(dplyr)`.

Comment: It says there is no package named dplyr `> library(dplyr)
Fehler in library(dplyr) : es gibt kein Paket namens ‘dplyr’`